# How to print a message for each async loop item?

Tags: ansible

Below is a snippet from a playbook. How can I print a message after the command is run for each loop item? Something like

```
image.pyc is now running for item1
image.pyc is now running for item2
```

and so on

```yaml
- name: Image Server(s)
  command: python3 image.pyc {{ item }} "{{ systemVersion }}"
  register: async_out
  async: 7200
  poll: 0
  with_items: "{{ hostinfo_input.hosts }}"
```

What I want is simply this

```yaml
TASK [Image Server(s)] ************* 
changed: [localhost] => (item=8m007) 
changed: [localhost] => (item=8m013) 
Running image.pyc for 8m007 
Running image.pyc for 8m013
```

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, extremely simple, untested, to be adapted to your use case specifically in terms of error/output control:

```yaml
    - name: Image Server(s)
      ansible.builtin.command: python3 image.pyc {{ item }} "{{ systemVersion }}"
      register: async_out
      async: 7200
      poll: 0
      with_items: "{{ hostinfo_input.hosts }}"

    - name: Wait for commands to finish
      ansible.builtin.async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: job_result
      until: job_result.finished
      retries: 720
      delay: 10
      loop: "{{ async_out.results }}"

    - name: Show async command output
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      loop: "{{ async_out.results }}"

   - name: Good guests always clean up after themselves
     ansible.builtin.async_status:
       jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
       mode: cleanup
     loop: "{{ async_out.results }}"
```

References:

- [`async` in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html)
- [`async_status` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/async_status_module.html)
- [`debug` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html)
- [Registering variables with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)

Comment: This won't come to "- name: Show async command output" task until 720x10 seconds are over. This is not what I want. What I want is this 



TASK [Image Server(s)] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=8m007)
changed: [localhost] => (item=8m013)





Running image.pyc for 8m007
Running image.pyc for 8m013

Comment: Please do not add needed code/info/output needed to answer your question in comments: [edit] your question. Thanks

Comment: `This won't come to "- name: Show async command output" task until 720x10 seconds are over.` <= wrong. It will stop if those commands are over before that deadline. 
So 7200s is a maximum time, as your requested with `async: 7200`.

Comment: Just to put away a possible misunderstanding: are you trying to display the output of the command synchronously (i.e. as it is played in real time on the target)? If yes, this is not possible. async or not, you will have to wait for the task to be finished before you get its result and have access to its `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Ansible` documentation for the `debug` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html

E.g.use it like this:

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    ip_addresses:
      - 10.0.0.10
      - 10.0.0.11
  tasks:
    - name: Task
      include_tasks: task.yaml
      loop: "{{ ip_addresses }}"
```

```yaml
# task.yaml
---
- name: Command
  ansible.builtin.shell: "echo {{ item }}"
  register: output

- name: Message
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: |
      - ip_address={{ item }}
      - ouput={{ output }}
```

Unfortunately this does not work with `async`. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22716.

Comment: How does the example relates to and answers the very minimal yet specif case posted in OP?

Comment: `Unfortunately this does not work with async` <= then for which exact reason did you add  an `include_tasks` in your edit? Why is this mandatory since it breaks `async`?

Comment: I was not sure whether `async` is a must since the question only states "How can I print a message after the command is run for each loop item." but the code containes `aszync`. The `include_task` was used because `block` was not possible with `loop`. If you prefer I can delete the full post @Zeitounator.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement as it is described currently

> *How can I print a message after the command is run for each loop item?*

could just be fulfilled by [`loop` output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)

> *This is for making console output more readable ...*

in example

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Image Server(s)
    command: "python3 image.pyc {{ item }} {{ systemVersion }}"
    register: async_out
    async: 7200
    poll: 0
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "Running image.pyc for {{ item }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Image Server(s)] *******************************************************
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=Running image.pyc for test1.example.com)
changed: [test2.example.com] => (item=Running image.pyc for test2.example.com)
...
```

The given example just provides the message after the command is sent over to the Remote Node and was started there. That is simply working because it is not defined who should provide (print) the message, the `loop` via `label`, `async` or the `script`. See also the comment of @Zeitounator ...